# How to call a jQuery function based on a GET parameter?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, get

I am using a jQuery plugin called [Stepy](http://www.wbotelhos.com/stepy/), to allow users to complete a 10-step form.

Stepy has a public function built in (click link above and scroll to bottom of page to see description) to allow users to jump between steps:

> $('#stepy').stepy('step', 2);

I'd like to have a link on a separate page that when clicked, will take the user to the form page, at a specific step within the form.

For example, going to `http://www.example.com/form.php?i=3,` will take the user to Step 3 of the form?  Is it possible to call a jQuery function based on a GET parameter?  If so, how would I implement something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
var i = document.location.search.match(/i=(\d+)/);
    if( i && i[1] ) {
    $( "#stepy").stepy( "step", parseFloat( i[1] ) );
    }
});
```

It will read the "?i=3" from url and match the number

Comment: Don't you want parseInt rather than parseFloat?

Comment: @steveax There is no floats anyway from the regex so the result will be the same. Besides: `parseFloat("08")
//8
parseInt("08")
//0`. I know the radix parameter but why bother.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch and handle url locations with jquery and the hashchange() plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Or for more advanced use with a lot of links like this, look into backbone.js url routing: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router